# Shapes Incompatible in Keras with CNN

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I am implementing a network that takes a 2d image and outputs a 3D binary voxels for it.
I am using an autoencoder with LSTM module.
The current shape of images and voxels are as follows:

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
>>> (792, 127, 127, 3)
>>> (792, 32, 32, 32)
```

792 RGB images 127 x 127

792 corresponding voxels with 3D Binary Tensor (32 x 32 x 32)

Running the following encoder model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, LeakyReLU, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Conv3D, MaxPool3D, GRU, Reshape, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow import keras



enc_filter = [96, 128, 256, 256, 256, 256]
fc_filters = [1024]

model = Sequential()
epochs = 5
batch_size = 24
input_shape=(127,127,3)

model.add(Conv2D(enc_filter[0], kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs)
```

yields the following:

```
ValueError: Shapes (24, 32, 32, 32) and (24, 1024) are incompatible
```

Can someone address why the shapes are incompatible? I tried removing layers and test others but all yields compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has a dense layer with 1024 output, but you are passing 32,32,32 shaped array.

You need to reshape your model output so that it has proper shape.

This is a dummy model, you need to change the parameters to find the suitable architecture.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, LeakyReLU, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Conv3D, MaxPool3D, GRU, Reshape, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np

# dummy data
x_train = np.random.randn(792, 127, 127, 3)
y_train = np.random.randn(792, 32, 32, 32)

enc_filter = [96, 128, 256, 2]
fc_filters = [1024]

model = Sequential()
epochs = 5
batch_size = 24
input_shape=(127,127,3)

model.add(Conv2D(enc_filter[0], kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(enc_filter[1], kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(enc_filter[2], kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(enc_filter[3], kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape)) # bottolneck
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32*32*32, activation='relu'))

model.add(Reshape((32,32,32)))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs)
```

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, 121, 121, 96)      14208     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 60, 60, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_24 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 60, 60, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)           (None, 54, 54, 128)       602240    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 27, 27, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_25 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 27, 27, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 21, 256)       1605888   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_26 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 10, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_26 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 10, 10, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_27 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 2)           25090     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_27 (MaxPooling (None, 2, 2, 2)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_27 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 2, 2, 2)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 8)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32768)             294912    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_10 (Reshape)         (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,542,338
Trainable params: 2,542,338
Non-trainable params: 0
```

In the summary, you can see I add a dense layer with 32x32x32 neurons and then reshape it.